# Clicking link with no ID,Tag etc in Selenium Java using htmldriver

Tags: java, selenium

How can i click the below? i Have tried using the XPath but no cigar!

My attempt:

```
WebElement submit = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/form/table[7]/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/a"));
submit.click();
```

This is the HTML:

```
<a href="#" onclick="return mysubit('save', window.document.jobform);">
    <img src="/shared/images/template_APC/order/submit.gif" width="90" height="17" border="0" alt="Submit Booking">
</a>
```

Comment: share complete source html with me please i can solve this problem then :)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said what the error being shown is but it could be that `td[1]` contains multiple `a` elements, or that something in the xpath you defined has changed. If you specifically want `td1`, specify in the xpath what you want from it (ie, it could be `//td[@name='cell1']`) etc. Hard coding specific indexes in xpath, I've found, is often prone to error.

For the xpath I'd go with:
`//table[@id/class/name='xxx']//td[@id/class/name='xxx']/a[contains(@onclick,'mysubmit')]` and click that. (I assume your method for submission is `mysubmit` and not `mysubit` as you've written).

Answer (score 0):

Using hard coded XPaths are prone to problems... depending on the browser they are run in, how often the structure of the HTML changes, etc. What I typically do in a situation like this is to look at the predecessors from the desired `A` tag. Hopefully you can find one with an `ID` or `class`, etc. that can serve as a start. You likely won't be *this* lucky but you hopefully will get the idea...

```
<div id="home">
    <a href="#" onclick="return mysubit('save', window.document.jobform);">
        <img src="/shared/images/template_APC/order/submit.gif" width="90" height="17" border="0" alt="Submit Booking">
    </a>
</div>
```

In this case you can use a CSS Selector to quickly get the `A` you want.

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#home > a")).click();
```

The CSS Selector, `"#home > a"`, means starting with the element with an `ID` of "home" (`#home`) find immediate children (`>`) that are `a` tags.

[CSS Selectors reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors)